# Connector as function input argument in modelica

Tags: function, modelica, openmodelica

is it possible to use a connector as function input argument? Somehow I am not able to get the following minimal example to run.

In the f.mo file I have

```
function f
  input Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin t;
  output Real p;
  algorithm
    p:=t.i*t.v;
end f;
```

In the test.mo I have

```
model test
   Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin t;
   Real V = f(t);
end test;
```

When I run the check of test.mo I get the error message

```
[1] 11:15:38 Translation Error 
[f: 2:3-2:52]: Invalid type .Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin for function component t.

[2] 11:15:38 Translation Error
[test: 5:3-5:16]: Class f not found in scope test (looking for a function or record).

[3] 11:15:38 Translation Error
Error occurred while flattening model test
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connectors cannot be used as function inputs. You can however do this:

```
function f
  input Real i;
  input Real v;
  output Real p;
  algorithm
    p:=i*v;
end f;

model test
   Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin t;
   Real V = f(t.i, t.v);
end test;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I have seen comments in introductory books that models and blocks cannot be used as input arguments, but I was not sure about connectors.

In dymola it seems to work. There I get only a warning.

Comment: Yes, Dymola is less strict unless you activate pedantic mode for check. The Modelica Specification 3.4 clarifies in chapter 12.2  what kind of components are allowed: _A function may only contain components of the restricted classes type, record, operator record, and function; i.e. no model or block components._

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is good and works, but in Modelica 3.4 section 12.6.1. another possibility was added that is closer to the original.

```
record R
  Real i,v;
end R;

function f
  input R t;
  output Real p;
  algorithm
    p:=t.i*t.v;
end f;

model test
   Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin t;
   Real V = f(R(t));
end test;
```

This was primarily motivated by models where you have more elements and it becomes tedious to list all of them. Since it is new functionality in Modelica 3.4 it is currently only active in Dymola if you set the flag `Advanced.RecordModelConstructor = true;`